# Examination whether a definition is well-defined

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral, step-function

Let f be a positive measurable function and $\varphi_k$ a monotone sequence of positive step functions such that $\varphi_k \leq \varphi_{k+1}$ and $\varphi_k \rightarrow f$ pointwise. Then we define the integral of f as follows:

$\int_D f d\mu:= lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \int_D \varphi_k$.

Now my question is why is the definition of the integral unique? How can I show, that I get for a sequence of step functions $\psi_k$ with the same properties as $ \varphi_k$ the same integral?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual approach is not to define the integral exactly that way. Instead define $\int f$ to  be the sup of $\int\phi$ over simple functions $\phi$ with $0\le\phi\le f$. Then prove the Monotone Convergence Theorem and it  follows that this definition is equivalent to the problematic "definition" you propose.

Comment: Yes, I know that the normal way is the other way round but I try to understand why my professor defined it like that. Suposse we know for every step function $\psi_k$ from above, that its integrals are limited by $lim_k \int_D \varphi_k$ does that help ?

Comment: Yes. It follows that $\lim\int\psi_k\le\lim\int\phi_k$; by symmetry (swapping the roles of $\psi_k$ and $\phi_k$) this shows that the two are equal.

Comment: Thank you a lot.